# how do I stop duplicate log lines when using log_buddy?

Tags: ruby, logging, heroku, nitrousio

I am using the `log_buddy` ruby gem.  However, I am getting duplicates in my console and in my log-manager:

```
last_response is going into the cache:
D, [2015-05-29T16:59:37.612481 #632] DEBUG -- : last_response is going into the cache:
```

The code where this appears looks like this:

```
  d "last_response is going into the cache:"
  d {last_response}
```

How do I stop the duplicates?